# How to get separate Arraylists Instances with other object

Tags: java, arraylist

In the following code, I am wondering how to use the other object. Specifically how do I get the two ArrayLists to have different values within them when I am passing them into the append method.

The following code is supposed to append two Arraylists together without modifying either of them.

I understand that in order to do this, I need to create a separate instance of the Arraylist "values", thats why I used the other object, but I am wondering how do I assign separate values to each instance of the Arraylist

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MergeSequence {


    public ArrayList<Integer> values;

    public MergeSequence(){

        values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }

    public void add(int n) {

        values.add(n);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return values.toString();
    }

    public MergeSequence append(MergeSequence other)
    {
        MergeSequence result = new MergeSequence();  // Create a new result object.

        // Iterate through the "local" ArrayList and add each value to the result
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
        {
            int j = values.get(i);
            result.add(j);
        }

        // Now, iterate through the "external" ArrayList and add each value to the result
        for (int i = 0; i < other.values.size(); i++)
        {
            int j = other.values.get(i);
            result.add(j);
        }

        result.toString();

        // Then return the result. Neither source ArrayList is modified.
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: A much easier way would be `result.values.addAll(values); result.values.addAll(other.values);`.

Comment: Your code does exactly what you need: ```#append``` method creates new  ```MergeSequence``` which contains items from both current instance and ```other```.  What is the question?

Comment: I want to print out the arraylist as a kind of final test, so I want to add values into the Arraylist and then run it through the append method to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

`toString` itself doesn't output anything to std-out. So after calling `result.toString();` you won't see the result in the console. You need to use `System.out.println(result)` to output the result.

By the way, printing the values in the `append` method is a side effect. It would be better to print the values outside of the `append`. E.g.:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MergeSequence a1 = new MergeSequence();
        a1.add(1);
        a1.add(2);
        final MergeSequence a2 = new MergeSequence();
        a2.add(3);

        final MergeSequence a3 = a1.append(a2);
        System.out.println(a1); // [1, 2]
        System.out.println(a2); // [3]
        System.out.println(a3); // [1, 2, 3]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a main method to test

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MergeSequence m1 = new MergeSequence();
        m1.add(1);
        m1.add(2);

        MergeSequence m2 = new MergeSequence();
        m2.add(3);

        MergeSequence m3 = m1.append(m2);
        System.out.println(m3.toString());
    }
```